# Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory performance

Tags: hibernate, configuration, entitymanager

We have about 150 classes mapped to 150 tables, and build the
`EntityManagerFactory` as follows:

Code:

```
Ejb3Configuration cfg = new Ejb3Configuration();

Class[] types = new Class[150] { ....};

for (int i=0; i<types.length; i++)
  cfg.addAnnotatedClass(types[i]);

EntityManagerFactory emf = cfg.buildEntityManagerFactory();
```

It takes a long time, about 20 seconds. Is there a way to speed up? or initialize lazily?
Thanks.
Dave